# Post Json string to Web Api Windows Store 8.1

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps

With webClient deprecated and SharpRest not working for Windows 8.1 I need to pass my json string to a web api.

> string js =@"[{""userName"":""jerin"",""userId"":""a""}]";
>
> var baseAddress="http://epub3.in/sample/android%20webservice/webservice/insertuser.php/";

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
         HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response =  httpClient.PostAsync("",
                new StringContent(
                    js,
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json")).Result;
              string sd = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();}
```

Now here baseaddress is a string which has url address. But even though I am getting IsSuccessStatusCode as true the json is not being entered.
and I am supposed to see the entered result in this **[link](http://epub3.in/sample/android%20webservice/webservice/viewusers)**
Android team is posting where their params value is

> **usersJSON=[{"userName":"jerin","userId":"3"}]**

According to @Jon's answer I edited my code where instead os System.Net.Http I am now using Windows.Web.http but its still not uploading

> ```
>         Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
>         Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage msg = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(new Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod("POST"), new Uri(baseAddress));
>         msg.Content = new HttpStringContent((js));
>         msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
>         Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(msg).AsTask();
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the HttpClient from the Windows.Web.Http namespace:

```
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), new Uri(baseAddress));
            msg.Content = new HttpStringContent(js);
            msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendRequestAsync(msg).AsTask();
```

Comment: I have updated my question. My earlier code was compiling, thanks for bringing to my notice that I should use Windows.Web.Http instead of System.Web.Http. Can you help me in posting as I still aint able to post.

Comment: You are doing it right and the json looks ok (array with one item) so it must be the server. Make sure that it is expecting a POST call and not expecting any other headers.

Comment: Well in android app its successfully posting but not in Windows app.
Does it have anything to do with the usersJSON= that gets added at the start? in Android code 
  `params.put("usersJSON", 
controller.composeJSONfromSQLite());`
So I think thats the one causing the error how can I put **userJSON=** also.

Comment: Install 'Fiddler' if you don't already have it and use it for testing the request. In the 'Composer' tab you can create the POST request and try different json strings.

Comment: Ty for introducing me to Fiddler. Yes I think its the web Api problem not my code's.